Where can I find Samsung Dex or HDMI connection log in Android?
I'm trying to find a Samsung Dex or HDMI connection log in the Samsung Galaxy S21 (Android 12) device.
My phone is rooted and I have looked in these packages but found nothing.

Samsung DeX : com.sec.android.desktopmode.uiservice
Samsung DeX home : com.sec.android.app.desktoplauncher
Samsung DeX System UI : com.samsung.desktopsystemui

Is there another directory or files I can look for?

How can I view and examine the Android log?
